# problem with cut_short_scale() for some values of binwidth of geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2

When trying to plot a histogram of a numerical variable from Ames housing dataset, cut_short_scale generate an error that I don't know how to solve for some values of binwidth of the histogram:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(AmesHousing)

ames_raw |> 
    mutate(`Bsmt Unf SF` = replace_na(`Bsmt Unf SF`, 0)) |> # impute missing values
    ggplot(aes(x = `Bsmt Unf SF`)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 90) +
    scale_x_continuous(label = label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale()))
```

If I run this chunk of code I get the following error:

`Error in break_suffix[bad_break][improved_break & !power10_break] <- names(lower_break[improved_break &  : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments`

If I use `binwidth = 80` or `binwidth = 100` for example the problem disappear. Why this happens? I could not figure it out. Is there a way of solving it without "manually" avoid certain values?

Note that the problem also disappears if I remove the line

`scale_x_continuous(label = label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale()))`

which leads me to think that the problem is with `cut_short_scale()`.

Edit: as suggested in a comment, rolling back to scales 1.2.1 solves the problem.

Comment: Right. The issue seems to be with `cut_short/long_scale` and was already reported as an [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/413) on GH. Seems to be related to the latest release. As suggested [here](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/413#issuecomment-1837583921) I can confirm that a "workaround" would be to roll back to scales 1.2.1.

Comment: thanks @stefan, I rolled back to 1.2.1 and everything seems to work